# Browser font size changes web layout

Tags: css, layout, fonts

My website layout changes if the user increases or decreases the browser's (any browser) font size.  Would someone kindly look at my website ([www.heathersoos.ca](http://www.heathersoos.ca)) and suggest (simple explanation please) how I can control this with css.  I would gladly include any coding from my site to help resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are going for there; the website seems to act correctly in Firefox.  If you think elements are not scaling correct as compared to the text, you might try changing your pixel references (px) to an equivalent (em) scale.

Comment: Hi Jason, Yes, the site looks fine as long as the font setting in the browser is set to 16 pt or to medium in Internet Explorer.  Unfortunately I am at a loss as to specifically how I need to adjust my css.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is being resized because certain `div` elements are being stretched or shrunk when the font size is resized, as they depend on the width of the contained text (they have `width:auto`). If you want to stop this from happening, you'll have to hard-code the width of each of element. This is generally considered a bad coding practice and is best to avoid, however. A better idea is to have the layout resize in a desirable way.

Comment: HI Jeff - THANKS so much for responding to my question!  Is it possible you could show me one example (using my site) and then I could repair the rest of the div tags on my own.  Tell me what you need from my site.  I would be grateful if I could exactly know what to do.  Thank You - Frank

Comment: I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1434204 - I'm afraid that would actually take awhile and I've got a lot of work right now. See this article, though: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/creating-a-fixed-width-layout-with-css/5314471

Comment: I'll Definitely take a look - Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jeff - just a quick follow up.  In my Body css I had the font set to 100%.  I changed it to a fixed size of 16px (which my site was based on) and it fixed the issue.  If you have a moment, please take a look and let me know if this makes sense - Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this would also work. Although I'm not sure what you mean by "makes sense" -- if it works, it works. =p

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the response.  I suppose what I was getting at with "makes sense" was if my repair was in keeping with the The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C).  I was wondering if I was following proper css protocol.  Anyways, again thanks for your replies! Frank